# Getting routes issue when I am using gem which provide swagger and rspec functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, swagger, rswag

I am getting this error when I run rspec test case.

swagger doc is getting created properly. I think I am missing some configuration changes related route for rspec.

I am sharing my spec file for reference purpose please check. let me know if you need any other details.

```
Failure/Error: raise ActionController::RoutingError, "No route matches [#{env['REQUEST_METHOD']}] #{env['PATH_INFO'].inspect}"
ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [POST] "/api/v1/orders"

describe 'Orders API' do
  path '/orders' do
    post 'Get menu for new business order' do
      tags 'Business Orders'
      parameter name: :business_order, in: :body, schema: {
        type: :object,
        properties: {
          latitude: { type: :string },
          longitude: { type: :string }
        },
        required: ['latitude', 'longitude' ]
      }
      response '200', 'success' do
        let(:business_order) { {latitude: 0.000,longitude: 0.00 } }
        run_test!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the `/api/v1/orders` route and any related config?

Comment: @Helen please check spec file I have updated the post.

Comment: Where does the `/api/v1` prefix come from?

Comment: ```config.swagger_docs = {
    'v1/swagger.json' => {
      swagger: '2.0',
      info: {
        title: 'API V1',
        version: 'v1'
      },
      basePath: '/api/v1'
    }
  }``` this is swagger helper

Comment: swagger ui and json working fine. Getting error when I run test case @Helen

Comment: It looks like base path from swagger_conf is used directly to test the routes (controller methods). Might be a workaround but haven't found one yet

Answer (score 6):

It's quite late to answer but I faced a similar issue while adding Rswag to my application which is on Rails 4.2

Adding the following lines to spec_helper.rb files will set the host for all request specs globally and resolve RoutingError.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :request) do
    host! "api.lvh.me"
  end
end
```